# Redirecting to third party link after clicking on Place Order in magento2.3

Tags: magento2

[image]
[image]I am all new to magento2.I am stuck in from where to start for linking third party url after clicking on PlaceOrder button on checkout.I referred many links,but could not find anything helpful.It would be great if anyone can help me out.Below is the screenshot about my scenario.

[image: png]

Answer (score 4):

Inside your payment method js implement **afterPlaceOrder** method. Which is responsible to redirect page. Ex:

```
afterPlaceOrder: function () {
    window.location.replace(url.build('oxipay/checkout/index'));
},
```

[Check this example method](https://github.com/oxipay/oxipay-magento-2.x/blob/master/Oxipay/OxipayPaymentGateway/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/oxipay_gateway.js#L47)

Comment: It will be great if u can ellaborate this 'oxipay/checkout/index',what does this particularly does,how can I implement it  for my case.Thanks.

Comment: 'oxipay/checkout/index' -> this should be your url where you want to redirect

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.